# What is config_whitelist.txt file and how is it used in u-boot?

Tags: u-boot

In u-boot source code, I see scripts/config_whitelist.txt with many CONFIG_XXX values.
What is the file and how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since this commit:

```
commit 371244cb19f9804711dd66e4281ff7979915fd2e
Author: Simon Glass <sjg@chromium.org>
Date:   Tue Sep 13 21:44:07 2016 -0600

Makefile: Give a build error if ad-hoc CONFIG options are added
```

The script `scripts/check-config.sh` will trigger an error during u-boot build if some CONFIG_XXX options are enabled in some include files (Kconfig mechanism should be used instead).
The file `scripts/config_whitelist.txt` establishes a list of exceptions to that rule.